# How to webscrape nested divs when elemenets are rendered with react?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is a website I'm trying to scrape: https://opyn.co/#/buy

[image]

I am trying to grap a div, but for some reason an empty list is returned. There has to be something I am doing wrong. Or perhaps a different approach is needed when dealing withs nested divs and websites running frameworks like react ?

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://opyn.co/#/buy'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
print(soup)

all_p = soup.find_all('div')
print(f"{all_p} | Status code: {r.status_code}")
```

What are the options, how to get the content of nested divs that are rendered by react?

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` doesn't *see* dynamic content. You might be better off using `selenium` or an API, if there's one.

Comment: I see, alright, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As advised in comments, you can use Selenium to get dynamic content:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36]")
chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
chrome_driver.get("https://opyn.co/#/buy")
time.sleep(2)  # wait to make sure that JS call pulled data that you need
divs = chrome_driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div')
divs_content = []
for div in divs:
    divs_content.append(div.text)
print(divs_content)
```

You will need to download an executable driver that suits you:
https://pypi.org/project/selenium/
For example that i provided you will need chrome webdriver:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
Just check what version your PC is running, download same version of executable and place it in the same folder as your python application.